# Converting column data type by using Spark data frame.

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a rdd, whose type is all string because it was read from a text file and there are about 20 fields. For example,

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq( ("1", "2.0", "three"), ("1", "2.0", "three")))
```

I want to use a dynamically generated structureType to create a dataframe for example -

```
val aStruct = new StructType(Array(StructField("id",LongType,nullable = true),StructField("id2",StringType,nullable = true), StructField("role",StringType,nullable = true)))

val df =  sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, aStruct)
```

Is there a way to automatically handle it, or I need to update each field on rdd with the correct type before creating dataframe.

Comment: Will they always be strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created the StructType your self and used it for dataframe, it is not possible to handle it automatically. I guess you want to use the same code logic for multiple data sources it seems.

1) If your data is from file and it is of type csv or any delimited data i suggest trying [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) 
There is an option called InferSchema, which identifies the data automatically and no need to create schema manually.

But, if you need to work with RDDs, there are two ways 1) create case class 2) create StuckTypes as you did dynamically based on data. For both of them, i dont think you will get what you expected.

please give some more details about the problem if you cannot work with spark-csv and i can try and provide solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following api on dataFrame in a loop to update the column.

```
def withColumn(colName: String, col: Column): DataFrame
```